# tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: inconsistency

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview, viewwillappear

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and iOS app development so I apologize if the answer to my question is simple. I'm trying to send a pointer of a GTGift object from one view controller to another. When I enter the following code, the object is send and stored in an instance variable of the second view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GTGift *selectedGift = [[[GTGiftStore sharedStore] allGifts] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    GTDetailViewController *dvc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
    [dvc setDetailGift:selectedGift];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

However, when I enter this code in the first view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    gift = [[[GTGiftStore sharedStore] allGifts] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    GTDetailViewController *dvc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

And this code in the second view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    GTGiftsViewController *gvc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"giftsVC"];
    detailGift = [gvc gift];
    NSLog(@"%@", detailGift);
}
```

detailGift returns null.

I can't for the life of me understand why, and it would be much more practical for my application if I could use an approach similar to the code segment that does not work.
If anyone can shine some light on this topic for me or point me in a different direction to complete the same task I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the word "instantiate" means what it says.  :-)

In `viewWillAppear` you're creating a brand new `GTGiftsViewController` object which knows nothing about the gift that's been selected in the first `GTGiftsViewController` object.

(The "storyboard way" of doing this kind of thing is to create a `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in your first view controller and do the work there.)

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try! Thank you! But I'm not quite sure how I would use that... I have a UITableView and I need to be able to determine which object in the table view is pressed and I don't know how I could do that without getting the indexPath from tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: If the segue is defined as coming from a table view cell, then that cell should be the `sender` in `prepareForSegue:sender:`.  You can ask the table view for the index path of a cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that and see how it goes!